# Search for lines that contain anything but alphabetic characters, dots and hyphens

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to create a RegEx pattern to match lines that contain anything but `a-zA-Z` ,  `.` and `-`

So I don't want to match `hello-world.txt` , but I would like to match `hello-world123.txt` or `hello-world(copy).txt`

Comment: you want to mach patterns that don't only have letters and . and -??

Comment: because the first sentence says you cant use [a-zA-Z.-].
And, what have you done until now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need match full string with:

- `/^[a-zA-Z.-]+$/`

  - `[a-zA-Z.-]` - match any of those characters
  - `+` - repeat one or more
  - `^`, `$` - anchor to start and end of the string

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to match strings with *just* a-z. or -
it would be

`^(?![a-zA-Z.-]+$).+$`

For `.+` you could substitute stuff you'd like to match (which could be anything)
like `[a-zA-Z.()\d-]+`